# ffmpeg : how to extract 1st video, english audio and french subtitle from video file in one command line?

Tags: ffmpeg

I have read many posts related to extracting streams per language with ffmpeg, but it seems that the `-map 0:m:language:xxx` is global, and goes for all streams.

Let’s say I have a video file that contains hopefully one english audio stream and some french subtitle streams, among possibly many other streams. I want to get a smaller file with the first video track, the (first) english audio stream and all the french subtitle streams.

If I run

```
ffmpeg -i "$file" -map 0:v:0 -vcodec copy -map 0:m:language:eng -acodec copy -map 0:m:language:fre -scodec copy -f matroska "${file%.*}.mkv_out"
```

I get in `file.mkv_out` all audio and subtitle tracks which are either french or english.

Is there a way to achieve this, without having any prior knowledge of track numbers in the original file ?

Thanks.

Comment: Hello, I added new answer, did you try what I suggested?

Comment: MichalH Thanks all. Reading what you proposed taught me yet again some ffmpeg niceties.
I chose the one-liner answer, but I learned from both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `ffmpeg` to pipe to another `ffmpeg` to avoid temporary files:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -map 0:v:0 -map 0:a:m:language:eng -map 0:s:m:language:fre -c copy -f matroska - | ffmpeg -i - -map 0:v -map 0:a:0 -map 0:s -c copy output.mkv
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid this can't be done in a single command because of the "first english audio stream" requirement. However, you can first extract all english audio streams and then pick the first one in second command like so:

Extract the first video, all english audio streams, all french subtitle streams to a temporary file:

```
ffmpeg -i "$file" -map 0:v:0 -map 0:a:m:language:eng -map 0:s:m:language:fre -c copy -f matroska "${file%.*}.mkv_out_tmp"
```

Then, from this file take the first stream (video), second stream (the first english audio), and all subtitles (all french):

```
ffmpeg -i "${file%.*}.mkv_out_tmp" -map 0:0 -map 0:1 -map 0:s -c copy -f matroska "${file%.*}.mkv_out"
```

And finally, delete the temporary file:

```
rm "${file%.*}.mkv_out_tmp"
```